# ASP.NET Page causes validation errors when navigating to another page - tab

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a couple of pages with standard asp.net validation controls such as RequiredFieldValidator etc inside my RadAjaxPanel.

As soon as I navigate to another tab in my RadTabStrip the page seems to force validation errors and pretty much "locks" the page even though non of the fields was selected to enter data.

Only once all the required fields was entered the page seems to release the "lock" and only then am I able to navigate to another tab / page without even submitting the page.

Any idea what might be causing the "lock" and forced validation errors on the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RequiredFieldValidators are failing as the fields are empty. These validators are fired client side and so they're stopping the postback (which will change your tab) from occurring.

I'm not sure how the tabbing works on a RadTabStrip, but for normal ASP Buttons there's a "CausesValidation" property on the button. If you set it to false, it'll stop any validators from being fired when pressed.

Comment: Thanks so much! On the RadTabStrip there was indeed the CausesValidation property which was set to True. Setting that to false solved it.